# AO criar pasta mkdir via PHP não fica acessível via FTP

Tags: php, ftp, mkdir

Estou em um servidor Apache/2.2.22 (Debian), e ao criar uma pasta para upload de uma imagem por exemplo a pasta fica totalmente inacessível via FTP. Não tem como deletar ou mesmo entrar na pasta.

```
$folder_name = 'pasta/date/arquivos/';

mkdir($folder_name, 0775, true);

copy('http://exeplo/img.jpg', $folder_name.'img_name.jpg');
```

Comment: Pode ser permissão do usuário que criou a pasta, dê um `ls -all` e vê os usuário dono da pasta.

Answer (score 0):

Você está criando a pasta com mkdir em um servidor linux, provavelmente as permissões vem travadas.

Crie a pasta com ftp_mkdir, assim você consegue definir o usuário que poderá abrir, e usar o mesmo para acessar com algum cliente como o filezila:

```
$dir = 'pasta';
$conn = ftp_connect('ft.seuhost.com');
$rs = ftp_login($conn, 'usuario_ftp', 'senha_do_usuario');
if (ftp_mkdir($conn, $dir)) {
    //ok
} else {
   //Erro
}
ftp_close($conn);
```